# Assign non-admin user permission to delete Tridion Building Blocks (Schemas, Component Templates, Page Templates etc.)

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, administration

I have created a user `TridReadWrit` (not admin user) in tridion and assigned to group `Developer`
The user has Read/Write permission on Tridion Building Blocks.

Below permissions are enabled for the user- Permission is set at 'Test Publication'>Property>Security Tab> Developer Group

- Publication Management
- Folder Management Structure Group Management
- Schema Management
- Component Management
- Component Template Management
- Page Management Page
- Template Management Publish To Content
- Distributor Workflow Management
- Category Management
- Template Building Block Management
- Virtual Folder Management

Also I tried set all permissions except -tried second time 'Test Publication'>Property>Security Tab> Developer Group

- Publication Management
- Permission Management

Both the situations the user `TridReadWrit` not able to delete Page Template(created by the same user)

Comment: Interesting question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Comment: Thanks for the info I have signed up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to provide delete permission to user or group. Go to building blocks folder containing PT and and choose Properties in the context menu.

In the security tab assign the Delete permission to user or group.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped.. Had been searching all day.. I wanted to assign it to a group